# Notepad++ XML - Delete Tags Conditionally Based on Child Tag Content

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace, xml

I am fairly new to Notepad++ and trying to use Regex to search for specific values in a  field and delete its Parent tag (and all contents including the  field).

Essentially I am trying to remove transactions that have certain Store ID's. The files are massive and there are thousands of entries I need to get rid of, sample below!

**Sample**

```
<Transaction>
                              <TxnHeader>
                                             <StoreId>6705</StoreId>
                                             <TillNumber>1</TillNumber>
                                             <TxnNumber>343243</TxnNumber>
                                             <StartDate>2019-02-02T07:42:45</StartDate>
                                             <TxnType>1</TxnType>
                              </TxnHeader>
                              <TxnItemLines>
                                             <TxnItemLine>
                                                            <DetailSequence>1</DetailSequence>
                                                            <ItemNumber>6304</ItemNumber>
                                                            <DeptNumber>168</DeptNumber>
                                                            <Quantity>1.000000</Quantity>
                                                            <LineValue>4.470000</LineValue>
                                             </TxnItemLine>
                              </TxnItemLines>
               </Transaction>
               <Transaction>
                              <TxnHeader>
                                             <StoreId>8351</StoreId>
                                             <TillNumber>1</TillNumber>
                                             <TxnNumber>327527</TxnNumber>
                                             <StartDate>2019-02-02T08:02:47</StartDate>
                                             <TxnType>1</TxnType>
                              </TxnHeader>
                              <TxnItemLines>
                                             <TxnItemLine>
                                                            <DetailSequence>1</DetailSequence>
                                                            <ItemNumber>6304</ItemNumber>
                                                            <DeptNumber>168</DeptNumber>
                                                            <Quantity>1.000000</Quantity>
                                                            <LineValue>7.310000</LineValue>
                                             </TxnItemLine>
                              </TxnItemLines>
               </Transaction>
               <Transaction>
                              <TxnHeader>
                                             <StoreId>7837</StoreId>
                                             <TillNumber>1</TillNumber>
                                             <TxnNumber>164728</TxnNumber>
                                             <StartDate>2019-02-02T08:19:47</StartDate>
                                             <TxnType>1</TxnType>
                              </TxnHeader>
                              <TxnItemLines>
                                             <TxnItemLine>
                                                            <DetailSequence>1</DetailSequence>
                                                            <ItemNumber>1902</ItemNumber>
                                                            <DeptNumber>154</DeptNumber>
                                                            <Quantity>1.000000</Quantity>
                                                            <LineValue>10.000000</LineValue>
                                             </TxnItemLine>
                              </TxnItemLines>
               </Transaction>
```

**Desired**

```
<Transaction>
                              <TxnHeader>
                                             <StoreId>6705</StoreId>
                                             <TillNumber>1</TillNumber>
                                             <TxnNumber>343243</TxnNumber>
                                             <StartDate>2019-02-02T07:42:45</StartDate>
                                             <TxnType>1</TxnType>
                              </TxnHeader>
                              <TxnItemLines>
                                             <TxnItemLine>
                                                            <DetailSequence>1</DetailSequence>
                                                            <ItemNumber>6304</ItemNumber>
                                                            <DeptNumber>168</DeptNumber>
                                                            <Quantity>1.000000</Quantity>
                                                            <LineValue>4.470000</LineValue>
                                             </TxnItemLine>
                              </TxnItemLines>
               </Transaction>
               <Transaction>
                              <TxnHeader>
                                             <StoreId>7837</StoreId>
                                             <TillNumber>1</TillNumber>
                                             <TxnNumber>164728</TxnNumber>
                                             <StartDate>2019-02-02T08:19:47</StartDate>
                                             <TxnType>1</TxnType>
                              </TxnHeader>
                              <TxnItemLines>
                                             <TxnItemLine>
                                                            <DetailSequence>1</DetailSequence>
                                                            <ItemNumber>1902</ItemNumber>
                                                            <DeptNumber>154</DeptNumber>
                                                            <Quantity>1.000000</Quantity>
                                                            <LineValue>10.000000</LineValue>
                                             </TxnItemLine>
                              </TxnItemLines>
               </Transaction>
```

The desired text above has completely remove the Transaction Tag that contain 8351

I tried a Regex find and replace (with nothing) using the query:

```
<Transaction>.*?<StoreID>8351</StoreID>.*?</Transaction>
```

and it ended up wrapping a massive chunk of the document from the top all the way down to the end of the first transaction containing 8351

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<Transaction>(?:(?!</Transaction>).)+<StoreId>8351</StoreId>(?:(?!<Transaction>).)+</Transaction>\R`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<Transaction>               # opening tag
(?:(?!</Transaction>).)+    # tempered greedy token, make sure we haven't </Transaction> before the following
<StoreId>8351</StoreId>     # literally
(?:(?!<Transaction>).)+     # tempered greedy token, make sure we haven't <Transaction> before the following
</Transaction>              # literally, closing tag
\R?                         # optional any kind of linebreak
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

More about [Tempered Greedy Token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)

Comment: Seems perfect, thanks!
and also thank you for breaking down the logic, good to know :)

Comment: @Jaevwyn: You're welcome, glad it helps.